# React Native (Expo) WebGL2 on iPad 15 is missing webgl2 extensions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, three.js, expo

When attempting to use Expo (SDK 43) in managed mode on an iPad Air 4th Gen (OS 15.0.2) with expo-three, expo-gl and a `<GLView>` with a model containing a SkinnedMesh and transparent textures, I receive the following warning:

```
Warning: THREE.WebGLRenderer: EXT_color_buffer_float extension not supported.
```

This is further confirmed with requesting the list of available extensions:

```
const ext = glContext.getExtension("EXT_color_buffer_float");
const availableExtensions = glContext.getSupportedExtensions();
...
Supported render extensions: APPLE_clip_distance,APPLE_color_buffer_packed_float,APPLE_copy_texture_levels,
APPLE_rgb_422,APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888,EXT_color_buffer_half_float,EXT_debug_label,EXT_debug_marker,
EXT_pvrtc_sRGB,EXT_read_format_bgra,EXT_separate_shader_objects,EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch,
EXT_shader_texture_lod,EXT_shadow_samplers,EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,IMG_read_format,
IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc,KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,OES_standard_derivatives,
OES_texture_float_linear,OES_texture_half_float_linear,WEBGL_compressed_texture_astc,
WEBGL_compressed_texture_etc,WEBGL_compressed_texture_pvrtc
Required extension EXT_color_buffer_float: NOT AVAILABLE!
...
```

But what is confusing is that the render capabilities indicate the WebGL2 is available:

```
console.log(`Render Capabilities: ${JSON.stringify(renderer.capabilities)}`);
...
Render Capabilities: {"isWebGL2":true,"drawBuffers":true,"precision":"highp","logarithmicDepthBuffer":false,
"maxTextures":16,"maxVertexTextures":16,"maxTextureSize":16384,"maxCubemapSize":16384,
"maxAttributes":16,"maxVertexUniforms":512,"maxVaryings":15,"maxFragmentUniforms":224,
"vertexTextures":true,"floatFragmentTextures":true,"floatVertexTextures":true,"maxSamples":4}
```

and `webglreport.com` in Safari indicates that WebGL2 is supported and that the EXT_color_buffer_float is available. In fact, the extension list differs from the webglreport.

### Versions

```
expo sdk: 43
expo-gl: 11.0.3
expo-gl-cpp: 11.0.1
expo-three: 6.0.1
react: 17.0.1
react-native: 0.64.2
three: 0.133.1
```

### Question

- How can I enable actual/complete WebGL2 support with the complete extension set as reported by webglreport with react-native on ios15?

Comment: Please narrow down your post to a single question. Which one of the 3 questions do you want us to help you with?

Comment: Down to a single question although answering any of them would answer all of them